# How to grep repeating lines in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am new to shell scripting.

I have a log file and I want a script to alert me if a line repeats. For example:

I have logs such as below:

```
2016-04-07 06:46:34,750 INFO: Error detected

2016-04-07 06:46:34,801 INFO: Case cleared

2016-04-07 06:46:35,744 INFO: Error detected

2016-04-07 06:48:34,558 INFO: Error detected
```

In the above logs, there are two repeated lines with 'Error detected' continuously. I want to get alerted if this happens.

Comment: There are no repeated lines in the example file you give.  Be precise with your question, and the answer will often be obvious.

Comment: Are you only interested in consecutive error lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk to print duplicated line:

```
awk -F ': ' 'seen[$NF]++ > 1' file
```

**Output:**

```
2016-04-07 06:48:34,558 INFO: Error detected
```

Comment: Looks like this will begin to print false positives when the next non-error line is encountered.

Comment: Don't we need to print all duplicate instances? May be OP can clarify?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '!NF{next} {orig=$0; $1=$2=""} $0==prev{print orig} {prev=$0}' file
2016-04-07 06:48:34,558 INFO: Error detected
```

Comment: anubhava's answer, `awk -F ': ' 'seen[$NF]++ > 1' file` is quite uncomplicated in comparison and it works, while your answer just overcomplicate things!

Comment: @anubhava's answer identifies all duplicates across the whole fie while you asked `How to grep repeating lines in a file?` and said `there are two repeated lines with 'Error detected' continuously. I want to get alerted if this happens.` and to do **THAT** you need the script I posted. In other words my script identifies **repeating lines** as you asked for while anubhava's identifies **duplicate lines** which is a very different and much simpler problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
awk -v prev="" '
$0 ~ /^$/ {next}
{
    info=$4" "$5;
    if(prev == info)
        printf("repeating line: %s\n",$0);
    prev = info;
}' infile
```

**Output:**

```
repeating line: 2016-04-07 06:48:34,558 INFO: Error detected
```

Comment: anubhava's answer, `awk -F ': ' 'seen[$NF]++ > 1' file` is quite uncomplicated in comparison and it works, while your answer just overcomplicate things!

Comment: @user3439894 it's pretty rude to tell people trying to help you that their `answer just overcomplicate things`. anubhava's answer is too simple for what you said you wanted. If it does what you actually wanted instead of what you said you wanted then just be happy you got an answer.

Comment: @EdMorton, First of all I'm not the one asking for help, zeewagon is! Secondly, my intent was not to be rude and sorry if it was taken that way, I was just making what I felt was a reasonable comment based on my interpretation of what the OP was asking for and the fact that anubhava's answer outputted what both your's and Ren's answers did and as I said "uncomplicated in comparison". As I'm constantly learning, I'm learning that sometimes more can be done is less code and be more efficient too. Maybe this isn't case, maybe it is... The OP will have to decide what code works best for his issue.

Comment: A script that produces the expected output given some sample input is the starting point for identifying a solution, not the end point. I assumed you were the OP since you were declaring in comments under multiple answers that anubhavas answer works and all the rest are needlessly complicated. As you mention it's best left up to the OP to decide which solution(s) "work" as opposed to just produce expected output given some sample input.

Answer (score 0):

This will report only the second consecutive error:

```
awk '
    /^[[:blank:]]*$/ {next}
    /Error detected$/ {errors++}
    !/Error detected$/ {errors=0}
    errors==2
' file
```

I'm assuming you would not need to be notified for the 3rd, 27th, etc consecutive errors.